# Express module that requires express

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

In my first NodeJS Express app, I installed express-couchUser.  From the root directory of my app I just used `npm install --save express-user-couchdb` and it was downloaded and installed just like I expected.  What makes me hesitate is that I now have a directory structure like this:

```
~/project$ find . -type directory -name "express"
./node_modules/express
./node_modules/express-user-couchdb/node_modules/express
~/project$ find . -type directory -name "express" -exec sh -c "cd {}; grep version  package.json " \;
  "version": "4.9.7",
  "version": "3.2.6",
```

So this seems express-user-couchdb requires express, and it uses it to server up some API routes like a[pi/user/signup](https://github.com/twilson63/express-couchUser/blob/master/index.js#L53).  I get this but it seems wrong to have two different versions of express like this.  Have I gone wrong or is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not done anything wrong. Node modules can define their own dependencies and own dependency versions. If you look at the express-user-couchdb module dependencies you can see it is looking for 3.2.6 (https://github.com/twilson63/express-couchUser/blob/master/package.json#L23) So any code within that module will use the express code for it's specified version.

You application is using a later version of express, so when you interact with express code you will be using the version your application requires.

Quickly looking at the express-user-couchdb docs it seems you can use a simple express 'use' to load it up in your express application, this is supported in your version of express so you shouldn't experience an issue.